# Get events titles and show it on spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

hello guys i'm trying to show all events titles in next week can you help i still have an error

```
function getevents() {


var sheet = mySpread.getActiveSheet();
 var now = new Date();
 var oneWeekFromNow = new Date(now.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60  *60 * 1000));
 var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, oneWeekFromNow).getTitle();
 var myEvents = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
       var tableauEvents = [];

   tableauEvents.push(events[i].getEvents(now, oneWeekFromNow))
   myEvents.push(tableauEvents);
   sheet.getRange(2, 2, myEvents.length, myEvents[0].length).setValues(myEvents)
   SpreadsheetApp.flush()

 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

this is the result if someone need

```
function getevents() {
var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(); 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var now = new Date();
var oneWeekFromNow = new Date(now.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60  *60 * 1000));
var events = cal.getEvents(now, oneWeekFromNow);
 var myEvents = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
       var tableauEvents = [];

       tableauEvents.push(events[i].getTitle())
       myEvents.push(tableauEvents);
       sheet.getRange(2, 2, myEvents.length, myEvents[0].length).setValues(myEvents)
       SpreadsheetApp.flush()

     }  
}
```

Comment: Looks like getting a reference to the calender with `CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();` solved your problem?